# Beginner Rock, Paper, Scissors Game Python Syntax

Tags: python

I created a Rock Paper Scissors game. It asks you if you want to play, takes your input, compares it with the random computer input, gives you the outcome, and then asks if you want to play again.

I don't know why it is not working. Please let me know how to fix it. Thank You

```
import random
import sys

#play
def play():
  print('want to play?')
if input()=='yes':
  print("Pick R/P/S")
  user = input()



# RPS
def RPS():
  x = random.choice( ['Rock', 'Paper', 'scissors'] )
print(x)
if x == 'Rock' and user == 'R':
  print('Tie')
elif x == 'Rock' and user == 'P':
  print('You beat Comp')
elif x == 'Rock' and user == 'S':
  print('Beat you')
#--------
if x == 'Paper' and user == 'R':
  print('Lost to comp')
elif x == 'Paper' and user == 'P':
  print('tie')
elif x == 'Paper' and user == 'S':
  print('you beat comp')
#---------
if x == 'scissors' and user == 'R':
  print('Beat comp')
elif x == 'scissors' and user == 'P':
  print('lost comp')
elif x == 'scissors' and user == 'S':
  print('tie')

#Play again
def playagain():
  print('Want to play again')
  play=input()
if play=='yes':
    RPS()
else:
    print("Thanks for playing")



play()
RPS()
playagain()
```

Comment: Remember that python uses indentation to define code blocks. So for example, the first `if` statement is really outside the function `play()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this should work. I have just edited you code, to make it a bit better:

```
import random
import sys
con_1 = True
ask_to_play = input('want to play?:')
if ask_to_play=='yes':
    while con_1:
        print("Pick R/P/S")
        user = input()
        x = random.choice( ['Rock', 'Paper', 'scissors'] )
        print(x)
        if x == 'Rock' and user == 'R':
            print('Tie')
        elif x == 'Rock' and user == 'P':
            print('You beat Comp')
        elif x == 'Rock' and user == 'S':
            print('Beat you')
    #--------
        if x == 'Paper' and user == 'R':
            print('Lost to comp')
        elif x == 'Paper' and user == 'P':
            print('tie')
        elif x == 'Paper' and user == 'S':
            print('you beat comp')
    #---------
        if x == 'scissors' and user == 'R':
            print('Beat comp')
        elif x == 'scissors' and user == 'P':
            print('lost comp')
        elif x == 'scissors' and user == 'S':
            print('tie')
        print('Want to play again(Y/n)?:')
        play=input()
        if play=='Y' or play == "y":
            con_1 = True
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing")
            con_1 = False
else:
    print("I hope you come back to play again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some indentation problems. Also you need to declare `user` variable in global scope. Have a look at this code:

```
import random
import sys
user = None

def play():
    print('want to play?')
    if input()=='yes':
      print("Pick R/P/S")
      global user
      user = input()


def RPS():
    x = random.choice( ['Rock', 'Paper', 'scissors'] )
    print(x)
    if x == 'Rock' and user == 'R':
      print('Tie')
    elif x == 'Rock' and user == 'P':
      print('You beat Comp')
    elif x == 'Rock' and user == 'S':
      print('Beat you')
    #--------
    if x == 'Paper' and user == 'R':
      print('Lost to comp')
    elif x == 'Paper' and user == 'P':
      print('tie')
    elif x == 'Paper' and user == 'S':
      print('you beat comp')
    #---------
    if x == 'scissors' and user == 'R':
      print('Beat comp')
    elif x == 'scissors' and user == 'P':
      print('lost comp')
    elif x == 'scissors' and user == 'S':
      print('tie')

def playagain():
    print('Want to play again')
    play=input()
    if play=='yes':
        RPS()
    else:
      print("Thanks for playing")

play()
RPS()
playagain()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there is problem with the code as it does not allow the user to pick R/P/S after play again.